# Loop through columns - SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to loop through the columns of all the tables in my database to select empty columns. I finally used raw sql and `.format` to get it to work, but how do I use SQLAlchemy to achieve the same result? Here is the code I've written:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

engine = create_engine('...')
conn = engine.connect()                                                                                                                                                                                 

tablemeta = MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True)

for t in tablemeta.sorted_tables:
    for col in t.c:                                                                                                                                                                                       
        s = select([func.count(t.c[str(col)].distinct())])                                                                                                                                                
        s = s.scalar()                                                                                                                                                                                    
        if s <= 1:                                                                                                                                                                                        
            print(s)
```

But this results in a KeyError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it to work:

```
for t in tablemeta.sorted_tables:
    for col in t.c:                                                                                                                                                                                       
        s = select([func.count(t.c[col.name].distinct())])                                                                                                                                                
        s = s.scalar()                                                                                                                                                                                    
        if s <= 1:                                                                                                                                                                                        
            print(s)
```